# Javascript onClick"display: none;" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a an image that when you click, this function runs.

```
function img(num) {
    var src = "images/main" + num + ".jpg";
    document.getElementById("popover-image").src = src;
    $("#sheet").css("display", "block");
}
```

When you click on the "X" (image), this function runs:

```
function close() {
    $("#sheet").css("display", "none");
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Here is how my image is set up:

`<img src="images/x.png" alt="Exit" onclick="close()" />`

Comment: How do you call that function? And why don't you use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of those `.css()` calls? And why do you mix vanilla DOM with jQuery?

Comment: Why use `css` if you can do the same with `show()/hide()`

Comment: Show how the event is added to the X

Comment: _"but it doesn't work_", great!

Comment: The close works fine for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/ZMwH6/

Comment: Thank you, @JohnKoerner your method of add the `.click()` worked!

Comment: @ThiefMaster I only mix them because I am very new to both JavaScript and jQuery. That's all I know how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

John Koerner's code:

```
$("#closeButton").click(function () {
    $("#sheet").css("display", "none");
});
```

Your event handler wasn't being attached properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this also, by using class name

```
( function($) {
  $(".btn-remove").click(function() {  
    $(this).css("display", "none");      
  });
} ) ( jQuery );
```

Answer (score -1):

We're all a little baffled that you read how to call the jQuery `.css` function but not `.show()`, `hide()`, or `attr()`.  For what it's worth, [here's the link to the hide function page.](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) JQuery is the answer. I can't think of a reason not to use it everywhere.

I think what you're trying to do is:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("img").on("click", function(num) {
     var src = "images/main" + num + ".jpg";
     $("#popover-image").attr("src", src);
     $("#sheet").attr("display", "block");
  });
  $("img[alt=Exit]").on("click", function() {
     $("#sheet").attr("display", "none");
  });
});
```

Comment: -1, `display` is css and not an attr. it's also wise to quote the value in an attribute selector

Comment: Thank you for the `.show()` and `.hide()`; I used them instead.