# javascript display :none function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly apologies if this is not a very good question, but I am not very familiar with Javascript at all. Secondly I did do research to find my problem I refer you to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298462/javascript-onclickdisplay-none-doesnt-work)

I wrote this very basic function

```
function hideBtn(){
var btn = document.getElementById("submitBtn").style.cssText="display:none";
}

echo'<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submitBtn" class="buttono" onclick="hideBtn()" />';
```

Which I want to hide my submit button after form is clicked as currently it is still displaying
[image]

Any help very much welcomed

Can it be that when the form is submitted the page is refreshed, and thus the function was not actually triggered?

Comment: `document.getElementById("submitBtn").style.display = 'none';` and `return false` onclick.

Answer (score 1):

> Can it be that when the form is submitted the page is refreshed, and thus the function was not actually triggered?

Yes, that's very likely to be the issue. If you don't want the page refreshed, don't use a `submit` button, or submit the form to another window, or use an `submit` event handler on the form element and prevent the default action.

Separately: It's best **not** to completely replace all of the styles on the element. Instead, just set the specific style you want:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("submitBtn").style.display = "none";
```

The `style` property on elements is an object with properties for each of the CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `submit` button, you need to stop form from submitting and refresh page.

Second thing, you are not using styles correctly to hide the button.

```
function hideBtn() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("submitBtn").style.display="none";
    return false; // Prevent form from submitting
}
```

Comment: `return false` from a `click` handler on a button won't do anything to prevent the form being submitted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Don't agree

Comment: It's not reliable cross-browser. Also, you need to have `return` in the `onclick` attribute in order for the function's return value to work even on those browsers where it works. What you've suggested to the OP so far is this: http://jsbin.com/zicidi/1/edit If you add `return` to the `onclick`, on **some** browsers (probably all modern ones), it'll work, yes.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to write:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("submitBtn").style.display = "none";
```

See more: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp